# How to cause Error in substrate without using ensure?

Tags: substrate

I want to just panic in a match statement without checking any conditions.

e.g.

```
pub fn add_citizen(origin, profile_hash:Vec<u8>) -> dispatch::DispatchResult {
     let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
     let citizenid_option = CitizenId::<T>::get(&who);
     match citizenid_option {
            Some(citizen_id) => {
                    ensure!(citizen_id, <Error<T>>::ProfileExists);

                }
                None => {
                
                }
                
            }

     let count = CitizenCount::get();
     Ok(())
}
```

Is there no other way to panic other than using ensure!

Comment: `ensure!` is not panicking, it is returning an `Err` of `DispatchResult `. If you really want to panic, you can just use `panic!`. But are you sure you want to panic? this will make the entire block invalid.

Comment: Maybe I should just use: ensure!(true, <Error<T>>::ProfileExists);, and returning Err is giving compilation error in match statement, as Ok(()) is returned at the end of function.

Comment: I don't understand your code, what do you want to do? If it is `Some(_)`, return `Err`? Can you explain the question in more detail?